# Binomial Normal Stats

Tags: statistics

1) The probability a pupil takes a bus to school is $0.3$. If a sample of $10$ pupils are chosen at random. Find the probability that

a)   exactly four pupils travel by bus.

b)  more than six pupils travel by bus.

***My Solution***

$P(S)=0.3$

$1-P(A)= 0.7$

$P(SSSSSSSSSS) = 0.3 \times 0.7 \times 0.7 \times 0.7 \times 0.7 \times 0.7 \times 0.7 \times 0.7 \times 0.7 \times 0.7 =0.0121060821$

Find the # of ways this situation can occur: $S'S'S'S'S'S' SSSS = 10!/6! = 5040$

Possibility of $4$ pupils travel by bus = $5040 \times 0.0121060821 = 61.014653784 = 62$.

*I tried this solution from my exercise book and I'm not sure if it is right. About part B: do I have to find out the number for six pupils first?*

---

2) If $Z\sim N(0,1)$ Find:

$P(Z>-2.46), P(Z<-0.725)$

***My Solutions:***

$P(Z>-2.46) = 0.99305$

$P(Z<-0.725) = 0.7642 - 15 = -14.2358$

*Are my solutions to these questions correct?
If you want to see the Distribution Table I can add a link.*

*Thank you*

Comment: Your "probabiliteis" aren't even in $[0,1]$. That cannot possibly correct.

Answer (score 1):

Some hints to get you to the correct solutions:

1. Let $X$ be the number of pupils who took the bus. Then $X \sim B(10, 0.3)$. (*Why?*).
   a. Asks for $P(X=4)$, wich is
   $$P(X=4) = \binom{10}4 \cdot 0.3^4 \cdot 0.7^6$$
   b. Asks for $P(X > 6) = P(X \ge 7)$. This is
   $$P(X>6) = P(X=7) + P(X=8) + P(X=9) + P(X=10)$$
2. This is a task of consulting the tables of the CDF for $N(0,1)$. Such a table gives you $P(X\le x)$ where $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $x\in[0,\infty)$ (usually up to at least $x = 6.66$).
   This function is called $\Phi$ and satisifes the equality
   $$\Phi(-x) = 1 - \Phi(x)$$
   wich allows you to get the values of $\Phi$ for negative $x$ from the table of values for nonnegative $x$. Since the normal distribution is a continuous distribution, you also have
   $$P(X\le x) = P(X < x)$$
   Together with
   $$P(X > x) = 1 - P(X\le x)$$
   you should now be able to work out the two values asked for.